# How to tidy up code into class files and methods

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am still learning Java and I am currently creating a program in Swing. I have been confused regarding when and when I should use methods and class files. I have created an application that has two cards, card 1: `homeJPanel` and card 2: `guestFixturesJPanel` and I want these to switch between each other on button click - which i have done to an extent. However, my code looks extremely messy and is hard to look at as all JPanels are in one method. I was wondering if there was any way I could put `guestFixturesJPanel` into a separate method or class file and still be able to call the card on button click. Is this possible? Also, does anyone know of any good tutorials that explain methods and class files well as I have been confused and this may be the solution to my problem.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.C14NMethodParameterSpec;   

public class Main 
{
    protected static final Component c1 = null;
    private JButton viewFixturesButton, loginButton, guestBackButton;
    private JLabel testTextJLabel, testTextJLabel2;
    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();

    public Main()
    {
        final JFrame window = new JFrame ("Main Game");

        final CardLayout c1 = new CardLayout();
        final JPanel container = new JPanel(c1);
        JPanel homeJPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        container.add(homeJPanel);

        JPanel centerJPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        testTextJLabel = new JLabel("TEST");
        centerJPanel.add(testTextJLabel);

        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        viewFixturesButton = new JButton("View Fixtures");
        loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        southPanel.add(viewFixturesButton);
        southPanel.add(loginButton);

        homeJPanel.add(centerJPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        homeJPanel.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        centerJPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        southPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        JPanel guestFixturesJPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        container.add(guestFixturesJPanel);

        JPanel guestCenterJPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel guestSouthPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        guestBackButton = new JButton("Back");
        guestSouthPanel.add(guestBackButton);

        guestFixturesJPanel.add(guestCenterJPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        guestFixturesJPanel.add(guestSouthPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        guestCenterJPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        guestSouthPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        viewFixturesButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                c1.show(container, "2");
            }
        });

        container.add(homeJPanel, "1");
        container.add(guestFixturesJPanel, "2");
        c1.show(container, "1");

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(container);
        window.setSize(600, 500);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setResizable(false);

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new Main();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could anyone explain why this question is getting down-votes?

Comment: Well in short yes you could pull your `guestFixturesJPanel` into a separate class. Is your question you don't know how?

Comment: I find the down-votes a bit unfair, too. The code isn't that bad, setting up controls is something that is often done in one big chunk. Netbeans generates code like this, too. You have already grouped some lines, you could move some to new methods. But I would just add some comments.

Comment: Yes, earlier I did try and call the Class through something like this `GuestClass guestClassCall = new GuestClass()`, but then i didn't know how to grab the `guestFixturesJPanel` and add it to the `container.add(guestFixturesJPanel, "3");`

Comment: Minor detail: when you say "class files", I think you mean "classes". [Class files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) are a lower-level detail that isn't relevant for this kind of code structuring discussion.

Comment: I'm not sure what they're called, I believe it may be `classes` as stated by you. I wan't the files with the C in the green circle as represented by Eclipse.

Comment: Yep, those are classes. Class files are the files ending with `.class` that's generated when your code is compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the `guestFixturesPanel` to a class of its own like this:

```
public class GuestFixturesPanel extends JPanel {
    public GuestFixturesPanel() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel guestCenterJPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel guestSouthPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JButton guestBackButton = new JButton("Back");
        guestSouthPanel.add(guestBackButton);

        add(guestCenterJPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(guestSouthPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        guestCenterJPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        guestSouthPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }
}
```

Then in your `Main` class you could instantiate a `GuestFixturesPanel` and add it to your container. This would preserve the functionality you have now, and extract the code out of your `Main` class.

```
GuestFixturesPanel guestFixturesPanel = new GuestFixturesPanel();
container.add(guestFixturesPanel, "2");
```

Not sure if that addresses the question you had, but I hope this helps.

Comment: That definitely looks more like what I am in need of. I will test this tomorrow, I don't have time at the moment. I'll let you know the results and hope it works. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. I have been procrastinating all day and then spent several hours trying to help another guy on SO - I now see why people get so frustrated when my questions aren't formatted properly :>. Anyways, the code worked flawlessly, I did try it like the above code, but when I tried it I created it exactly the same as `Main` without the `homeJPanel`. Thanks!

Comment: Also, through doing this I am now trying to create a button in GuestFixtures that goes back to `homeJPanel`, but c1 gives the error `c1 cannot be resolved`

Comment: @HarryKitchener You can't access c1 from your new panel class. Hard to explain in a comment... But you need to pass a reference to you `Main` class to your subpanel. Write a method on main that is something to affect of `goHome()` which would select it as the active panel. Like I said hard to explain in a comment but if you are still unclear post a new question and I'll take a look.

Comment: Is there any possibility you could post it on here please?